# Cant understand visibility of method via interface

Tags: java, facebook

Im working with open source library to test facebook api features https://code.google.com/archive/p/facebook-test-java-api/

Now what I'm trying to do is to change my test user name. I dived into code of this library and found the following:

```
public interface FacebookTestUserAccount
{

 // irrelevant methods
    /**
     * Gives access to change settings for the test user.
     * @return An {@code AccountSettingsChanger} responsible for updating the account settings.
     */
    AccountSettingsChanger changeAccountSettings();
// irrelevant methods
}
```

Now my test goes like this:

```
@Test
    public void updateNameOfTestUser(){
        List<FacebookTestUserAccount> allTestUsers = store.getAllTestUsers();
        FacebookTestUserAccount facebookTestUserAccount = allTestUsers.get(0);
        facebookTestUserAccount.// here after dot I cant see method changeAccountSettings() 
    }
```

Since my refrence method is the type of the interface, and the method is defined in interface, what Im struggling with:

**Why I cant see the method in my test class?**

thats the code of getALL();

```
 public List<FacebookTestUserAccount> getAllTestUsers() {
        init();

        String jsonResponse = get("/%s/accounts/test-users", applicationId);

        JSONObject accounts = parseJsonObject(jsonResponse);

        LinkedList<FacebookTestUserAccount> result = new LinkedList<FacebookTestUserAccount>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) accounts.get("data");
        for (Object element : jsonArray) {
            JSONObject jsonUser = (JSONObject) element;
            result.add(buildFacebookAccount(jsonUser));
        }

        log.debug("* Found [{}] accounts on Facebook ", result.size());

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to write `changeAccountSettings()` after the dot and compile? It could just be that your IDE failed to load the suggestions or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons for your problem:

1. Your IDE failed to load the auto-complete suggestions. To check this, just write `changeAccountSettings()` after the dot, and try to compile. (I suspect this is your problem, because you phrased your question like "Why can't I see this..?")
2. You have two different `FacebookTestUserAccount`s in your codebase, and you have imported the wrong one.

Comment: ok I found the problem, I have imported old version with maven, and I was cheecking out the updated one, which have more features....